# Active Directory authentication with initial page open (mvc 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory

I want first page available to everyone and through form (no popup) and Active Directory authentication.

Everything is fine if I use Windows authentication but as I said I don't want popup and I do want first page aviable and with  login form fields. Is this possible? If so how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can setup your login controller's login function with [AllowAnonymous] which will make it visible to user even if user is not logged in and rest of the controllers you can specify [Authorize] ... Infect if you create a new template project with type of project as Intranet which will automatically setup your project with windows authentication.

Comment: But with windows authentication Enabled the registration doesn't recognise my AD login and password. Any ideas why? Should I map it somehow to my AD server?

Comment: You have to implement the logic to validate your login against your AD   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279140/configure-asp-net-mvc-for-authentication-against-ad