# New MVC5 application with windows auth install to IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have created a brand new web application project through Visual Studio 2013 with windows authentication enabled.  Nothing has been done to the site besides creating it and debugging it.  When debugging the site works fine (logged in automatically with the correct machine/user displayed in the top right), however, once I deployed the site to my local machine I am met with a prompt for user name and password.

If I click cancel when asked for creds I get the following error:
`HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.`

Steps I have taken:

1. Created the site in IIS
2. Specified that the app pool use .NET 4.0
3. Turned on just Windows Auth from the authentication options and turned off anonymous auth
4. Added the site to my host file with my IP
5. Deployed the site with the web publish option in VS

My webconfig has the following system.web:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

One extra bit:
When I edit the bindings and remove the host name and set the port to something like 82 I can navigate to it via `localhost:82`

What am I missing with this basic deploy?  I have searched for bare bones articles on deploying a generic site with windows auth to IIS7 but have not come up with anything.

Comment: what do you have as `authentication` in the `web.config`?

Comment: Added an edit to my question

Comment: did you followed all the steps? my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10279322/28004) to a question

Comment: As far as I can tell I have indeed done everything you have laid out here.

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer for debugging and a different browser after deploying?  To the best of my knowledge, IE is the only browser that will automatically pass windows credentials, all others will prompt for it.