# ASP.Net MVC 5 Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory, windows-authentication, visual-studio-2022

I know that this has been asked before here, but I couldn't find a way to fix this. I'm using VS 2022/MVC 5/IISExpress and these are my configs:

web.config:

```
    <authentication mode="Windows"  />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

And these lines in my vbproj file:

```
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>disabled</IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
```

According to the approved solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279140/configure-asp-net-mvc-for-authentication-against-ad) the above should work, but doesn't. I am logged in to Windows using my domain account and have been added to local administrators group (Of course I'm not a domain admin, just a standard user). I can login to my web app using my own domain account, but not with other domain accounts (I have tried two different accounts). Any credentials other than mine is rejected by application. How can I fix it?

Comment: Two questions: 1. How are you logging in with your own account? (does it ask you for credentials?) and 2. What *does* happen when you try a different account?

Comment: @GabrielLuci 1. When I open site, a pop-up dialog appears and asks for credentials. When I enter my own credentials, it accepts and displays home page. 2. When I enter other credentials, that pop-up dialog disappears and re-appears again, asking for credentials again.